What's the real absolute maximum output voltage of the 74LVC07?
Datasheets for the 74LVC07, such as this one from TI, and this one from Nexperia, state that the absolute maximum output voltage for the open-drain outputs (in high state) is +6.5V.
There is a table footnote, though:

[2] The output voltage ratings may be exceeded if the output current ratings are observed.

So, which is it? Is the absolute maximum +6.5V or not?

The TI datasheet has a similar footnote but mentions only negative voltages, that may be exceeded. This sounds plausible to me.

It's not clear what the actual output structure is. My (conservative) interpretation is that the note applies only to negative input voltages, not to positive ones since there is no current rating for positive "clamping voltage" nor is there any indication that there is such a thing that will happen. For Vin < 0, the voltage drop will be approximately one P-N diode drop and the power dissipation will be limited.
If the output transistor breaks down or there is some built-in zener clamp, the power dissipation will be at least an order of magnitude higher.
Also, those are absolute maximum ratings. Going outside the recommended range of 0 to 5.5V (especially without current limiting) is potentially going to negatively affect reliability.
